# Writing Websocket server

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, server

I'm writing websocket server using nodejs using this article as my guid

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Client_Handshake_Request

I'm listening for the /chat route to send a websocket handshake response to the client as following :

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(req.url === '/chat') {
        let clientWebSocketKey = req.headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
        const concatenatedKey = clientWebSocketKey + '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11';
        const acceptKey = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(secret).digest('base64');
        res.setHeader('Upgrade','websocket');
        res.setHeader('Connection', 'Upgrade');
        res.setHeader('Sec-WebSocket-Accept', acceptKey);
        res.setHeader('Connetion', 'keep-alive');
        res.statusCode = 101;
        console.log("WEBSOCKET GET REQUEST");
        console.log(res.statusCode); 
    }

    if(req.url === '/') {
        res.write('Main route');
        res.end();
    }
});
```

also i'm launching http GET request using postman with the following headers but I never get a correct handshake .

```
Host: localhost:3000/chat
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

I'm expecting doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

Comment: If you use the socket.io library you could really simplfy that

Comment: @AndrewHansen I'm required to hard code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you probably know, WebSocket is a seperated protocol that uses HTTP just for making the handshake. Thus, it might be that Postman doesn't parse the 101 status code.

I would recommend you to write your request with node.js using the `upgrade` event as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_upgrade)

Comment: I really appreciate your clarification. Thank you so much.